how to have a legend for size of geom_points() and also set the size of the dots themselves?
I am trying to plot a sort of bubble plot but i am unable to set the size of the dots and have a legend explaining how the sizing works.
These are two examples which combined give me the expected output. The first one allows me to set the size of the dots. The second one prints the legend. I need to have both: sized dots and a legend explaining the size. But if i have one, i am unable to get the other, too. Would be great to be able to set the title for the "size legend", too.
Any clue?
library("ggplot2")

x <- sample(2000, 1000, replace=T)
y <- sample(2000, 1000, replace=T)
category <- sample(c("one", "two"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
size <- sample(2000, 1000, replace=T)/50

df <- data.frame(x, y, category, size)

# first example with sized dots
dev.new()

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=category))+
   geom_point(shape=21, color="black", size=df$size)+
   guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=40)))

# second example with the legend
dev.new()

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=category, size=size))+
   geom_point(shape=21, color="black")+
   guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=40)))

If there is a duplicate question, please link it and mark this one. Thanks!

You have negative sizes, and your first plot tries to literally interpret those? The second one works like you need it to, but might want change the size scale, e.g. + scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.1, 10), name = "my size label")? Not quite sure what you are after.

To literally interpret the size (like size = df$size) you would use + scale_size_identity(), but again, this doesn't make sense with negative sizes.

@Axeman, you're right, i should have done it differently. this is updated and still not working.

What do you mean exactly by not working? What about the second plot is "wrong" in your opinion?

thing is that the second plot is not sizing the dots in the actual plot, right? i need to size the dots according to the variable.

It is. The dots are not all the same size, right?

actually, yes. but then how come that dots in the first plot are way bigger?

Because you are setting the size to a fixed number. This is not what you should do. You should let ggplot scale the size to your variable, by using aes() as in your second plot. Then ggplot will also create a matching legend for you. If the size is too small for your taste, change the scale to include a wider range, as I showed in my first comment. A size of 40 (as in your adjusted legend) is super big though, and it will make all your text etc look tiny.

And if you do want those literal sizes, and a legend, then as I said before you can use scale_size_identity()

Maybe for the 2nd chart you might add scale_size_area(max_size = 40, breaks = c(10, 30)) if you want the largest bubble to be 40 wide.

@Axeman. i made it but if you want to add an answer, go ahead! if not, i will do it, to make it clear how to do it.

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=category, size=size))+
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=8), title = "New category"))


